# Display thumbnail in teaser with WYSIWYG editor

Tags: media, wysiwyg, nodes

I need to show a thumbnail in the teaser of my blog post. 
My blog post already have images inserted with WYSIWYG editor and i can see it in the default view of the blog entry.
Then in the front page i have the teaser version of this blog entry and what can i see is the body of the entry and three dots '...'
How can I display the image in the teaser and display as thumb?

I also try to create a thumb field just for the teaser, so i kind of divid this two tasks (which is not ideal for my client since he would like to upload less image possibile to save time), at that it work but I still see the three dots in the teaser

Any suggestions?

Comment: What happens when you insert the image right at the front of the text? It sounds like you have text trimmed before the image tags. Try modules like this one (there are a few) [Field Formatter Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_formatter_filter) and if it does not work consider using the summary input of the body field for the teaser display.

Comment: Cool tips thanks. I will try it and let you know :)